# WordPress Gutenberg Register Multiple Custom Blocks

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to create several custom blocks within Gutenberg. It is only allowing me to register one at a time.

I have tried combining `recipe_card_block()` and `first_block()` but that doesn't help.

Both blocks work correctly individually. If I remove `recipe_card_block()`, `first_block()` will appear in the inserter (and vice versa). However, when both are present only the first one will show up. Changing the order in which they are registered affects which one appears.

It seems to me they are somehow overwriting each other, but I don't see how that's happening.

Here is the code in `functions.php`.

```
function recipe_card_block(){
    wp_register_script(
        'recipe-card-script', // name of script
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/recipe-card.js', // path to script
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor', 'wp-components' ) // dependencies
    );

    wp_register_style(
        'recipe-card-style',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/recipe-card-style.css',
        array( 'wp-edit-blocks' )
    );

    register_block_type('gadam/recipe-card', array(
        'editor_script' => 'recipe-card-script', // default script / script to define behavior within the editor
        'style'         => 'recipe-card-style' // default styles
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'recipe_card_block' );

function first_block(){
    wp_register_script(
        'first-block-script', // name of script
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/first-block.js', // path to script
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor' ) // dependencies
    );
    // styles for editor view
    wp_register_style(
        'first-block-editor-style',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/first-block-editor-style.css',
        array( 'wp-edit-blocks' )
    );
    // default styles
    wp_register_style(
        'first-block-style',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/first-block-style.css',
        array( 'wp-edit-blocks' )
    );

    register_block_type('gadam/first-block', array(
        'editor_script' => 'first-block-script', // default script / script to define behavior within the editor
        'editor_style'  => 'first-block-editor-style', // styles for editor view
        'style'         => 'first-block-style' // default styles
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'first_block' );
```

This is the code in `first-block.js`

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { RichText, BlockControls, InspectorControls, AlignmentToolbar, FontSizePicker } = wp.editor;
const { Fragment } = wp.element;

registerBlockType( 'gadam/first-block', {
    title: 'First Block',
    icon: 'welcome-learn-more',
    category: 'custom-blocks',

    attributes: {
        content: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'html',
            selector: 'p'
        },
        alignment: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        fontSize: {
            type: 'number',
            default: 18
        }
    },

    edit( { attributes, className, setAttributes } ) {
        const { content, alignment, fontSize } = attributes;
        const fontSizes = [
            {
                name: 'Small',
                slug: 'small',
                size: 14
            },
            {
                name: 'Normal',
                slug: 'normal',
                size: 18
            },
            {
                name: 'Large',
                slug: 'large',
                size: 24
            }
        ];

        function onChangeContent( newContent ) {
            setAttributes( { content: newContent } );
        }

        function onChangeAlignment( newAlignment ) {
            setAttributes( { alignment: newAlignment } );
        }

        function onChangeFontSize( newFontSize ) {
            setAttributes( { fontSize: newFontSize } );
        }

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <BlockControls>
                    <AlignmentToolbar
                        value={ alignment }
                        onChange={ onChangeAlignment }
                    />
                </BlockControls>
                <InspectorControls>
                    <AlignmentToolbar
                        value={ alignment }
                        onChange={ onChangeAlignment }
                    />
                    <FontSizePicker
                        fontSizes={ fontSizes }
                        value={ fontSize }
                        onChange={ onChangeFontSize }
                    />
                </InspectorControls>
                <RichText
                    key="editable"
                    tagName="p"
                    className={ className }
                    style={ { textAlign: alignment, fontSize: fontSize } }
                    onChange={ onChangeContent }
                    value={ content }
                />
            </Fragment>
        );
    },

    save( { attributes } ) {
        const { content, alignment, fontSize } = attributes;
        const baseClass = 'wp-block-gadam-first-block';

        return (
            <div class="container">
                <div class={ baseClass }>
                    <RichText.Content
                        style={ { textAlign: alignment, fontSize: fontSize } }
                        value={ content }
                        tagName="p"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },
} );
```

And finally, this is `recipe-card.js`

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { RichText, BlockControls, InspectorControls, AlignmentToolbar, FontSizePicker } = wp.editor;
const { Fragment } = wp.element;

registerBlockType( 'gadam/recipe-card', {
    title: 'Recipe Card',
    icon: 'index-card',
    category: 'custom-blocks',

    attributes: {
        content: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'html',
            selector: 'p'
        },
        alignment: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        fontSize: {
            type: 'number',
            default: 18
        }
    },

    edit( { attributes, className, setAttributes } ) {
        const { content, alignment, fontSize } = attributes;
        const fontSizes = [
            {
                name: 'Small',
                slug: 'small',
                size: 14
            },
            {
                name: 'Normal',
                slug: 'normal',
                size: 18
            },
            {
                name: 'Large',
                slug: 'large',
                size: 24
            }
        ];

        function onChangeContent( newContent ) {
            setAttributes( { content: newContent } );
        }

        function onChangeAlignment( newAlignment ) {
            setAttributes( { alignment: newAlignment } );
        }

        function onChangeFontSize( newFontSize ) {
            setAttributes( { fontSize: newFontSize } );
        }

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <BlockControls>
                    <AlignmentToolbar
                        value={ alignment }
                        onChange={ onChangeAlignment }
                    />
                </BlockControls>
                <InspectorControls>
                    <AlignmentToolbar
                        value={ alignment }
                        onChange={ onChangeAlignment }
                    />
                    <FontSizePicker
                        fontSizes={ fontSizes }
                        value={ fontSize }
                        onChange={ onChangeFontSize }
                    />
                </InspectorControls>
                <RichText
                    key="editable"
                    tagName="p"
                    className={ className }
                    style={ { textAlign: alignment, fontSize: fontSize } }
                    onChange={ onChangeContent }
                    value={ content }
                />
            </Fragment>
        );
    },

    save( { attributes } ) {
        const { content, alignment, fontSize } = attributes;
        const baseClass = 'wp-block-gadam-recipe-card';

        return (
            <div class="container">
                <div class={ baseClass }>
                    <RichText.Content
                        style={ { textAlign: alignment, fontSize: fontSize } }
                        value={ content }
                        tagName="p"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },
} );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who may come across this in the future:

Look at the top of the two `js` files I posted. The constants declared in one file are shared by all subsequently registered blocks. So what's happening is when I register `first-block` the constants are defined. When I register `recipe-card` it tries to define the constants at the top of the file, but they were already defined by `first-block`.

The code for `recipe-card.js` should remove the constants that are already defined by `first-block`.

```
registerBlockType( 'gadam/recipe-card', {
    title: 'Recipe Card',
    icon: 'index-card',
    category: 'custom-blocks',

    attributes: {
        content: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'html',
            selector: 'p'
        },
        alignment: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        fontSize: {
            type: 'number',
            default: 18
        }
    },

    edit( { attributes, className, setAttributes } ) {
        const { content, alignment, fontSize } = attributes;
        const fontSizes = [
            {
                name: 'Small',
                slug: 'small',
                size: 14
            },
            {
                name: 'Normal',
                slug: 'normal',
                size: 18
            },
            {
                name: 'Large',
                slug: 'large',
                size: 24
            }
        ];

        function onChangeContent( newContent ) {
            setAttributes( { content: newContent } );
        }

        function onChangeAlignment( newAlignment ) {
            setAttributes( { alignment: newAlignment } );
        }

        function onChangeFontSize( newFontSize ) {
            setAttributes( { fontSize: newFontSize } );
        }

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <BlockControls>
                    <AlignmentToolbar
                        value={ alignment }
                        onChange={ onChangeAlignment }
                    />
                </BlockControls>
                <InspectorControls>
                    <AlignmentToolbar
                        value={ alignment }
                        onChange={ onChangeAlignment }
                    />
                    <FontSizePicker
                        fontSizes={ fontSizes }
                        value={ fontSize }
                        onChange={ onChangeFontSize }
                    />
                </InspectorControls>
                <RichText
                    key="editable"
                    tagName="p"
                    className={ className }
                    style={ { textAlign: alignment, fontSize: fontSize } }
                    onChange={ onChangeContent }
                    value={ content }
                />
            </Fragment>
        );
    },

    save( { attributes } ) {
        const { content, alignment, fontSize } = attributes;
        const baseClass = 'wp-block-gadam-recipe-card';

        return (
            <div class="container">
                <div class={ baseClass }>
                    <RichText.Content
                        style={ { textAlign: alignment, fontSize: fontSize } }
                        value={ content }
                        tagName="p"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },
} );
```

Comment: Did you maybe find a better solution to this? I feel like the order in which I register my blocks shouldn't matter. Also, some blocks need different imports than others and with this way I always have to check all blocks. There has to be a better way. :(

Comment: What I ended up doing is creating an entirely separate `dependencies.js` file that only had the imports and always loading that first. You may be able to check if the needed import already exists somehow in each block, but I never bothered to try it out. It's worth noting I don't have exact numbers on the effect my solution had on overall load times, but anecdotally it wasn't enough that I noticed a difference.